# ¿Como recargar la pagina al ejecutar consulta php con ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatables

En mi datatable si doy clic en el botón editar, me muestra un modal con información, cuando doy clic en guardar me muestra una alerta y después me recarga la pagina, pero hay alguna posibilidad que primero al dar clic al boton guardar este se redireccionando y al mismo tiempo que mande la alerta? ya que por el momento es al revés, primero alerta y después se redirecciona.

Mi archivo donde hago mi consulta lo tengo asi:

```
    <?php

  include('../conexion/dbconect.php');
  $id_u = $_POST['id_usuario'];
  $periodoEdit = $_POST['periodoEdit'];
  $bajaInstitucionEdit = $_POST['bajaInstitucionEdit'];
  $bajaActAcademicaEdit = $_POST['bajaActAcademicaEdit'];

  $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE siacc_usuarios SET  periodo = '$periodoEdit', baja_inst = '$bajaInstitucionEdit', baja_act_acade = '$bajaActAcademicaEdit' WHERE id_usuario = '$id_u' ";  

  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlUpdate);
  //echo $sqlUpdate;
if (!empty($result)) {
    echo("<script>alert('Datos actualizados correctamente'); window.location.href = 'cat_usuarios';</script>");
  } else {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    //echo("<script>alert('Hubo un error'); window.location.href = 'cat_usuarios.php';</script>");
  }
 
  echo "Task Update Successfully";  




  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Y mi js, donde tengo mi ajax lo tengo asi:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'execUpdUser.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
              id_usuario: $('#id_usuario').val(),
              periodoEdit: $('#periodoEdit').val(),
              bajaInstitucionEdit: $('#bajaInstitucionEdit').val(),
              bajaActAcademicaEdit: $('#bajaActAcademicaEdit').val()
      },
      success: function(response) {
         window.location.href = 'cat_usuarios';
         alert('Datos actualizados correctamente');
      }
    });
```

Antes no lo hacia con ajax y con mandar un echo después de mi consulta, entonces si me lo hacia

Answer (score 1):

Desde PHP puedes refrescar con lo siguiente:

```
$archivoActual = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
header("refresh:1;url=" + $archivoActual +"));
```

El número en el parámetro refresh india el tiempo que deseas demore en hacer el refresh, es decir si pones 5, recién a los 5 segundos hará el refresh.

En javascript o sea del lado de ajax, podrías probar:

```
window.location.reload();
```

o

```
location.reload();
```

En algún caso, ejemplo cuando se ejecuta esto al hacer un onclick, es necesario agregar un return false, o sea quedaría así.

```
location.reload();
return false;
```

Por último podrías probar:

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
```

Cuidado con el Alert, no se si te conviene al hacer una redirección, te diría que lo retires, hagas las pruebas y después decidas, hay mejores opciones que un alert, como un tostify, o alert de bootstrap, entre otras.

Espero te sirva, necesitaría algo más de información para indicarte cual sería la adecuada, pero espero logres resolverlo con una de ellas.

Quedo a las órdenes.